# How do you check if first and last name are unique only on creation?

Tags: django, forms

I have the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

and I have the following form:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['short_name', 'long_name']
```

Right now I am using this form for both update and create.

I would like this form to raise ValidationError if someone is trying to create a Person with the same short_name and long_name.

However, I do not want to raise an exception if a user is modifying an existing user's data.

I have thought about writing a clean method to check if `Person.objects.filter(long_name=X, short_name=Y).count()` returns anything but this condition incorrectly fails when I am modifying an existing instance.

How would you change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `unique_together` as illustrated [here in the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) at the model level

Answer (score 1):

An existing instance is one that has a value for `pk`. So just check for that in your `clean()` method:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def clean(self):
        if self.pk is None and Person.objects.filter(long_name=self.long_name,
                                                     short_name=self.short_name).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Someone already has those names!")
```